# Como impedir a duplicidade no cadastro/alteração de nomes/razão social

Tags: c#

Em um cadastro, c# windows form, onde utilizo CPF´s ou CNPJ´s qual a melhor forma de impedir a duplicidade de nomes/razão social na inclusão ou na alteração.

Por exemplo pode acontecer que na alteração o usuário informe um nome/razão que já esteja cadastrado.

Usar nomes para pesquisar não seria indicado pois os espaços entre podem ser interpretados como diferenciadores ex: "William da Silva" e "William da   Silva".

Qual a melhor abordagem para este problema?

Comment: DÊ detalhes do que você está fazendo. Isto é um banco de dados, uma lista? Coloque um código.

Comment: A melhor forma de impedir a duplicidade é conferindo se já existe outro cadastrado... Quanto aos nomes, duas ou mais pessoas podem ter o mesmo nome, e serem pessoas diferentes, independente do número de espaços. Agora, um sistema bem feito já não guardaria espaços duplos aonde não é pra ter espaços duplos, convenhamos. Quanto à sua pergunta, precisa de mais detalhes, pois como está é muito ampla e aberta à imaginação. Sugestão de leitura: **[Ask]** e **[Help]**.

Comment: Aprenda REGEX, expressoes regulares, somente desta forma é possivel fazer isto. E isto tem que ser feito consultando o banco de dados fazendo a analise e antes de alterar no banco inserir um REGEX para validação

Comment: Agradeço a todos pois as respostas já me deram um norte, apesar do tema ser vago. Depois crio um post com dúvidas mais específicas.

Answer (score 1):

A forma que uso para verificar é através da seguinte consulta

```
select Id from Tabela where Id <> @Id and Cpf = @Cpf
```

Dessa forma, se a consulta retornar algum resultado, significa que o registro já existe na base de dados.

O parâmetro `@Id` é o sua chave primaria logo quando for um novo registro, seu valor será `0` comparando somente o segundo parâmetro, sendo esse o que queres que não seja duplicado, que no meu exemplo é o `@Cpf`.

Answer (score 1):

Olha o que eu faria nesse caso é colocar no campo da sua tabela ele como
constraint, assim o banco não deixei você inserir um registro com mesmo valor.
Ele te geraria um erro. Você pode pegar esse erro no Try catch e informar ao usuario.

Procure ler sobre constraint em campos de tabela.